# Python CV2 does not detect obvious lines

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sm9K.png)

I am new to computer vision. The goal is to detect the nearly vertical black lines in a lattice and rotate them to vertical. I applied a Hough line transform. However it is not seeing the obvious black lines.

Here is the code. What did I get wrong?

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(binary_image, 50, np.pi/180, threshold=50, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=500)

image_with_lines = binary_image.copy()
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    angle_rad = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)  
    angle_deg = np.degrees(angle_rad)
    
    if 88 <= angle_deg <= 92:  
        cv2.line(image_with_lines, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0,0,255), 5)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: they are not lines, they are points. HoughLines expects continuous lines. Maybe you can apply morphology to the image before trying to detect lines, so the individual points get merged in a continuous shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround solution. I did the following steps

1. Threshold and inverted the binary image.
2. Dilated the image to create a continuous point close to a complete line. Can use 'DILATE_PARAMETER' to adjust the dilation.
3. Adjusted cv2.HoughLinesP parameters

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#Parameter to control dilation to create a continuous line.
DILATE_PARAMETER = 2

original_image = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg')
binary_image = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg',0)
binary_image[binary_image<127] =0
binary_image[binary_image>=127] =255

#Inverting the image.
binary_image = cv2.bitwise_not(binary_image)

kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
binary_image = cv2.dilate(binary_image, kernel, iterations = 2)
for _ in range(DILATE_PARAMETER-1):
        binary_image = cv2.dilate(binary_image, kernel, iterations = 2)
    
#print(np.unique(binary_image))
#print(binary_image.shape)

#Can check the images after inverting and dilation
cv2.imwrite('binary_image.jpg',binary_image)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(binary_image, 1, np.pi/180, threshold=150, minLineLength=400, maxLineGap=20)
for line in lines:    
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    angle_rad = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)  
    angle_deg = np.degrees(angle_rad)
    
    if 80 <= angle_deg <= 100:  
        print("Found Line : ", line[0], " in angle :", angle_deg)        
        cv2.line(original_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, 5)

cv2.imwrite('image_with_lines.jpg',original_image)
```

> output

```
Found Line :  [580   1 608 526]  in angle : 86.94711748520757
Found Line :  [600  34 608 514]  in angle : 89.04515874612783
Found Line :  [597  35 606 526]  in angle : 88.94988945946136
Found Line :  [270  93 277 516]  in angle : 89.0519294294594
Found Line :  [581  36 606 510]  in angle : 86.98086815086273
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much for taking the time to write this!!